# Google Charts - How to pass a dynamic variable in options.series?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm making a reporting tool that uses Google Charts graphics.
I want to create Combo Charts but the number of datas is dynamic so i have to pass a variable "nbEGP" in options.series:

```
/* Création de graphique Google Chart */

function drawChart(array, title, div, type, nbEGP) {

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

// Set chart options
var options = {
    'title' : title,
    'width' : '80%',
    'height' : '600',
    seriesType : "bars",
    series : {
            nbEGP : {
            type : "line"
        }
    }
};
```

...

```
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

but it doesn't work. If i try to display options.series I can see it did not put the value of my variable but the name "nbEGP".

Comment: Please add your solution to the answer section and mark is the accepted answer -- that way future people can see what you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally managed doing like this:

```
// Set chart options
var options = {
    'title' : title,
    'width' : '80%',
    'height' : '600',
    seriesType : "bars",
    series : ""
};

myObj = {};
myObj[nbEGP] = {type : "line"};
options.series = myObj;
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it solved my problem of dynamically changing the series type of the last column :)